# Is it possible to view this json data whilst sending it to the server with console.log?

Tags: javascript, json, function, express, promise

I would like to view the JSON data being sent to the server as well as send it. However, I am having trouble understanding what promises do to this function.

If I `console.log()` the body of the function I get `Promise { pending }`. I can't `console.log(users)` outside the promise because 'users' is out of scope.

Therefore, is there a way for me to view the data within the body of the code provided?

```
function getAll(req, res, next) {
    userService.getAll().then(users => res.json(users)).catch(err => 
next(err)); 
}
```

The expected result is some JSON data in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
function getAll(req, res, next) {
    userService.getAll().then(users => {
        console.log(users)
        res.json(users)
    }).catch(err => 
next(err)); 
}
```